# Universal Label Decorator Plugin for Eclipse in Zend Studio

Tags: zend-studio

Does anyone know how to use this plugin http://www.jave.de/eclipse/labeldecorator/ in Zend Studio 10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to wgal i was able to solve this. You must do this: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=50293&p=123018#p123018 to get dropins folder work in zend 10 :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download a zip package from http://www.jave.de/eclipse/labeldecorator/ (download section). Then extract it in dropins folder which is located in Zend Studio installation directory (e.g c://Program Files/Zend Studio). After that run Studio and the plug-in should be installed.